# ng-hide doesn't removed from class even when ng-show is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Requirement** **:** To Show and Hide a div.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-show="IsSuccess">
  My Div Content
 </div>
```

**HTML after page load**

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="false">
```

**HTML after updated from controller (http post call)**

```
 <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="true">
```

ng-show is `true` but still class contains `ng-hide`

How to resolve this issue ?

For reference, below is my controller

```
myController.controller('AuthenticationController',
    function AuthenticationController($scope, $location, authDataService, loginDuration) {
        $scope.Login = {};
        $scope.IsSuccess= false;

        $scope.login = function () {
            authDataService.authenticateUser($scope.Login, $scope).then(
                        function (status) {
                            if (status === 200) {
                                if ($scope.message == 'Login failed') {
                                    $scope.IsSuccess= true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    $scope.IsSuccess= false;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        function (data) {
                            $scope.ErrorMessage = data.Message;
                        }

                    );
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think there is no need to add ``class='ng-hide' ``,  ngShow directive handles this by itself.

Comment: yes, I didn't add that class. It was handled by ng-show. Please read carefully

Comment: when the page was loaded it was automatically added by ng-show. Hope it clarifies your doubt

Comment: There is no `$scope.IsSuccess` in your code sample, is that correct ?

Comment: i wonder where the IsSuccess is coming from either im blind or it is not defined in your controller

Comment: where is `$scope.IsSuccess` in your controller ? from where you change `$scope.IsSuccess = true; or $scope.IsSuccess = false;` ?

Comment: you would need <div ng-show="fail">

Comment: $scope.IsSuccess= false; value is updated in controller. Sorry I did wrong copy paste before. Please see updated controller

Comment: Your question updated after adding my comments. Anyways set ``$scope.IsSuccess`` to either true or false like you doing it for ``$scope.fail``

Comment: Sorry Sameer, Please see updated controller. I have already tried that $scope.IsSuccess= true;

Comment: are you sure, after post call, you getting `IsSuccess as  true` ?

Comment: @Everyone : why it coming out as ``<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="true">``. I mean ng-hide is still there

Comment: @gauravbhavsar : yes Gaurav, I am getting right results. : why it coming out as ``<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="true">``. I mean ng-hide is still there

Comment: I think it is because you are passing $scope to your authenticateUser function you dont need that and try defining $scope.IsSuccess outside the function call

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a Plunker?

Comment: If you start with `ng-show="true"` then you won't get `class="ng-hide` in the first place. If you change the attribute(!) afterwards it has no effect. Your controller seems to set `$scope.IsSuccess` to `false` after a successful login.

Comment: @zeroflagL : please don't go in details. $scope.IsSuccess= true; means login is failed and I want to show message div. So the logic is correct. Please suggest something else

Comment: why you are getting `class="ng-hide"` is because at first when the html got rendered `div` will  be shown and then made hidden or not based on the `scope value` from the controller. so in order to make it more effective `ng-show` itself adds the `class="ng-hide"` to itself

Comment: I m also facing the same issue @Gaurav123. I think its a bug from angularjs side. Try adding / removing display: none; display: block class instead of ng-show / ng-hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `authDataService.authenticateUser` is returning a promise that looks like it's outside of the angular context, angular doesn't know when the scope changes. In that situation, you need to add `$scope.$apply()`

```
if ($scope.message == 'Login failed') {
    scope.IsSuccess= true;
}
else {
    $scope.IsSuccess= false;
}

$scope.$apply();
```

** **Edit: Extended Explanation** **

Because you asked for more details about this, I'll try to explain a little further.

[$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) needs to be called when outside of the angular context. Here's what I mean by outside of the angular context:

```
$scope.login = function() {

    // inside angular context
    console.log('a');

    setTimeout(function() {

        // outside angular context
        console.log('b');
        $scope.hello = 'b';

        // $scope.$apply() needs to be called
        $scope.$apply();

    }, 1000);

    // inside angular context
    console.log('c');
    $scope.hello = 'c';

};
```

In this example, here's the output to the log:

```
a
c 
// $scope.$apply() is assumed at this point
b
```

Angular knows it needs to adjust its bindings after the last line of `$scope.login()` is processed, and so `$scope.$apply()` is assumed then, but Angular doesn't know if you have any other callback functions that might be called later on through another context, another context being `setTimeout` or jQuery's `$.ajax` or `$.Deferred`, etc. If that different context modifies the $scope, then you need to call `$scope.$apply()` to manually update the Angular bindings.

Comment: _"a promise that looks like it's outside of the angular context"_ - How exactly does such a promise look like?

Comment: If using $.Deferred for example

Comment: Sure, but can't tell that by looking at this code ^^

Comment: Awesome !! It works. 
Can you please give more details how it worked.

Comment: @Gaurav123 Sure thing, I edited the answer to extend the explanation. Let me know if that's clear or not!

Comment: @MikeRichards : Thanks for providing more details. Much Appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I would change your HTML to show 
`<div ng-hide="IsSuccess">
  My Div Content
 </div>`

and then in your angular file

```
$scope.login = function () {
    if(<!-- logic to hide or show-->){
        $scope.IsSuccess = false;
    }else{
        $scope.IsSuccess = true; 
    }             
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: yes, you have understood it well. but this solution doesn't work.

Comment: why it coming out as ``<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="true">``.  I mean ng-hide is still there

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow. I think it will help.

Answer (score -1):

HTML code:

```
<button class="show-more-btn ng-hide" ng-show="hasMoreItemsToShow()" ng-click="showMoreItems()"">Show More</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('.show-more-btn').removeClass('ng-hide'); 
       }, 3000);
```